# SML list summing

Tags: sml

I'm very new to SML and I am trying a list exercise. The goal is sum up the previous numbers of a list and create a new list. For example, an input list `[1, 4, 6, 9]` would return `[1, 5, 11, 20]`.

This is my solution so far, but I think the issue is with how I'm defining the function.

```
fun rec sum:int list -> int list = 
    if tl(list) = nil then 
      hd(list)
    else 
      hd :: sum((hd(tail) + hd(tl(list)))::tl(tl(list)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides that you are using rec as a function name, then you have some minor issues to work on.

- The explicit type annotation you have made is treated as an annotation of the function result.
  Thus, according to what you have written, then it should return a function and not the expected 
  list. This is clearly seen from the below example:

  ```
  - fun rec_ sum : int list -> int list = raise Domain;
  val rec_ = fn : 'a -> int list -> int list
  ```
- Your should be careful of using the head and tail functions, when you don't do any checks on the 
  number of elements in the list. This could be done with either the length function, or (even 
  easier and often better) by pattern matching the number of elements.
- Your code contains sum as a function call and tail as an variable. The variable tail has never 
  been defined, and using sum as a function call, makes me believe that you are actually using rec 
  as a keyword, but don't know what it means.

  The keyword rec is used, when defining functions using the val keyword. In this case, rec is 
  needed to be able to define recursive functions (not a big surprise). In reality, the keyword fun 
  is syntactic sugar (a derived form) of val rec.

The following 3 are examples of how it could have been made:

The first is a simple, straight forward solution.

```
fun sumList1 (x::y::xs) = x :: sumList1 (x+y::xs)
  | sumList1 xs = xs
```

This second example, uses a helper function, with an added argument (an accumulator). The list is constructed in the reverse order, to avoid using the slow append (@) operator. Thus we reverse the list before returning it:

```
fun sumList2 xs =
    let
      fun sumList' [] acc  = rev acc
        | sumList' [x] acc = rev (x::acc)
        | sumList' (x :: y :: xs) acc = sumList' (y+x :: xs) (x :: acc)
    in
      sumList' xs []
    end
```

The last example, show how small and easy it can be, if you use the standard list functions. Here the fold left is used, to go through all elements. Again note that the list is constructed in the reverse order, thus it is reversed as the last step:

```
fun sumList3 []      = []
  | sumList3 (x::xs) = rev (foldl (fn (a, b) => hd b + a :: b) [x] xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this -

```
fun recList ([], index, sum) = []
  | recList (li, index, sum) =
    if index=0 then
        hd li :: recList (tl li, index+1, hd li)
    else
      sum + hd li :: recList (tl li, index+1, sum + hd li)

fun recSum li = recList (li, 0, 0)
```

In your case  -

```
recSum([1,4,6,9]) ;
```

will give

```
val it = [1,5,11,20] : int list
```

also don't use `rec` as fun name  -it keyword .